# Realm queue questions in swift

Tags: swift, realm

I'm attempting to make a single background thread to handle all realm interactions.  I'm seeming to have issues

So my approach was to define a `realmQueue`

```
internal var realmQueue = dispatch_queue_create("DataRecorder.realmQueue",
                                                 DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL)
```

And my assumption was I'd try to do EVERY single realm interaction on this queue itself.

Is there a way to figure out (other than stepping through the code) which thread Realm is expecting?

I'm getting thread access errors as I try to wrap my calls in

```
dispatch_async(realmQueue) {
  // do realm stuff
}
```

I'm pretty sure somewhere I'm accessing realm wrong but I'm having trouble tracking things down.

What's the best approach to debug these threading issues?

Answer (score 0):

The rule-of-thumb with Realm is that objects cannot be passed between threads and each thread will have its own instance of a `Realm` object. If you try and pass a `Realm` instance or an `Object` subclass across threads, an exception will occur.

The recommended way to handle moving a Realm interaction to a new thread is to simply re-fetch the same Realm object on the new thread, and then updating it from there. The easiest way to refetch an object is to pass its primary key across the thread and call `objectForPrimaryKey()` to fetch it.

Finally, while writes to Realm files block access on other threads, reads do not, and so you would hopefully only need to sparingly use cross-threaded interactions when performing fetches with Realm. :)

Comment: I'm actually try to ONLY do writes and from what i can see i'm on the correct thread but its still erring out.  Very confusing.... i shall look deeper.